# Submit formdata and an input value to AJAX post

Tags: php, ajax

I have a form with multiple fields, one of them is register_id. I also have an upload button where I can upload multiple images through a modal. Once the user presses submit I have an ajax call sending both the register_id as well as the form data. However, I am having problems accessing the form data.

This is my javascript that is executed when the user presses submit from the modal window where they upload the images:

```js
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var regId = (document.getElementById('register_id').value);
    var formdata = new FormData(this);
    var postData =  { formdata: formdata, regId: regId };
    var dataString = JSON.stringify(postData);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'uploadImages.php',
        type: 'POST',
            data: {myData:dataString},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = "<p>"+response+"</p>";
        },
    });
});
```

In my PHP I would like to create a custom folder depending on the register Id passed and get all the images. I am managing to echo the register id but I am having trouble getting the formdata. As soon as I echo `$obj->formdata;` I get:

> jquery.min.js:2 POST http://localhost/CanvasCreator/uploadImages.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
>
> send @ jquery.min.js:2
>
> ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
>
> (anonymous) @ uploadImages.js:7
>       dispatch @ jquery.min.js:2
>       v.handle @ jquery.min.js:2

This is my php code:

```php
<?php
    $obj = json_decode($_POST["myData"]); 
    $regNo =  $obj->regId;
    $formData =  $obj->formdata;
    $all_files = $formData;
    echo($formData);
    echo($regNo);

    $path = 'SourceImages/'.$regNo.'/';
    mkdir($path, 0777, true);

    $extensions = ['tif'];

    $all_files = count($_FILES['file']['name']);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $all_files; $i++) {
        $uploadOk = "";
        $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'][$i];
        $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'][$i];
        $file_ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['file']['name'][$i])));
        $file = $path . $file_name;
        if (!in_array($file_ext, $extensions)) {
            $uploadOk = $uploadOk . 'Extension not allowed: ' . $file_name. '</br>';
        }

        if ($file_size > 2097152) {
            $uploadOk = $uploadOk . 'File size exceeds limit: ' . $file_name. '</br>';
        }

        if (file_exists($file)) {
            $uploadOk = $uploadOk . 'File already exists: ' . $file_name. '</br>';
        }
        if ($file_size <1) {
            $uploadOk ='Choose at least one image file' . $file_name. '</br>';
        }

        if($uploadOk != ""){
            echo  $uploadOk;
        }else{
            if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$file)){
                echo "File saved: ".$file_name."</br>";
            }else{
                echo "File not saved: ".$file_name."</br>";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can not expect `$_FILES` to get populated, when you send your data by stuffing it into a custom JSON data structure of your own making.

Comment: Is there a work around to pass both $_FILES and a variable to PHP?

Comment: The FormData object has an `add` method, use that to add your register_id value. And then send _only_ that FormData object, without trying to specify your own ContentType.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044798/how-to-use-formdata-for-ajax-file-upload

Comment: append `regId`  in fromdata as https://stackoverflow.com/a/58269310/6309457